# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes

Tags: java, exception, aes, decode, encode

I have an ArrayList which contains some objects. Object is a container for login/pass. 
I try to decode them because i have to serialize them into local file for recreation after another launch.
Problem is during encryption I recieve

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1039)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:983)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
```

And I completely don't understand why. In my opinion Base64 should deal with this. But maybe I don't understand properly its meaning.
I use to encrypt/deccode

```
public class Move
{
    private static Move instance;

    String key = "pT5IkWNR90gJo5YM";
    String initVector = "RandomInitVector";
    Cipher cipher;


    private Move()
    {
//      try
//      {
//          cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
//      }
//      catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e)
//      {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
    }


    public void saveData(ArrayList<Account> dataToSave)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Config.SERIAL_FILE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(encrypt(dataToSave));
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayList<Account> loadData()
    {
        ArrayList<Account> loadedData = new ArrayList<Account>();
        File f = new File(Config.SERIAL_FILE);
        if (f.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(Config.SERIAL_FILE);
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
                loadedData = (ArrayList<Account>) in.readObject();
                in.close();
                fileIn.close();
            }
            catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            loadedData = decrypt(loadedData);
        }
        else
        {
            loadedData = new ArrayList<Account>();
        }
        return loadedData;
    }


    private ArrayList<Account> encrypt(List<Account> decrypted)
    {
        ArrayList<Account> encrypted = new ArrayList<Account>();

        try
        {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            for (int i = 0; i < decrypted.size(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] login = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(decrypted.get(i).getLogin().getBytes()));
                    encrypted.add(new Account(login.toString(), "pass"));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encrypted;
    }


    private ArrayList<Account> decrypt(List<Account> encrypted)
    {
        ArrayList<Account> decrypted = new ArrayList<Account>();

        try
        {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.size(); i++)
            {
                byte[] login = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted.get(i).getLogin()));
                decrypted.add(new Account(new String(login), "pass"));
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decrypted;
    }


    public static Move getMove()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Move();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do encrypt/decrypt passwords instead of hashing?

Comment: Because I keep them in the file and load them during launching an application.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AES block size is always 128bit, it must receive input in multiples of this number.

Smaller input must be padded to 16 bytes, and the type of padding specified to the algorithm.

Using "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" will do the trick.

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

If you use NoPadding, then you must implement your own padding for encryption, and make sure  to remove it from the resulting string in decryption.

Comment: Do I understand correctly padding is some kind of completion?

Comment: Yes for example if your password is "1234", AES would expect something like "1234000000000000".